# Factors to consider when swapping a battery with a power supply

Tags: power-supply, batteries

I'd like to swap an 18V lithium-ion battery with an 18V DC power supply for use in battery-powered hand tools (cordless drill, reciprocating/circular saw, weed whacker, etc.).

Logistical issues aside, are there any electrical considerations where a fully-charged battery may behave differently than a power supply of the same voltage?

For example, these tools are likely highly inductive loads, and the datasheet for [this](https://www.trcelectronics.com/ecomm/pdf/pm100.pdf) power supply states outputs are protected to short circuit conditions (~5.5A draw). Even so, I am not sure how this compares to the characteristics of a li-ion battery.

Comment: Switch mode power supply might not be the best choice here. A transformer plus rectifier may be better since the tool has some worst-case scenario that can be very challenging, like cold start, and stall. You need something simple and robust and can take some beat.

Comment: The inrush current is the initial AC input current when power is applied to the power supply.  It says nothing about the maximum output current the supply can produce.

Comment: @PeterBennett Ah I see. So in this case, would the output specification "overcurrent protection" be more along the lines of what I meant (though obviously not ideal to short the output)? So it will provide ~5.5A no matter what?

Comment: Yes, I'd expect the overcurrent protection to trip on something over a 5.5 volt draw.  A battery won't have a hard limit on the maximum current, but most power supplies will.

Comment: 'swap with' isn't clear. Are they battery powered, and now you're changing to an AC supply, or AC powered and you want to change to a battery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things that define a voltage source:

1) Voltage
2) Source resistance

Batteries have a different source resistance than a regular supply, this affects its ability to source current to whatever load\device you are using. Make sure the battery will source enough current.

The other thing is voltage, unlike a regulated voltage source, batteries are unregulated, meaning the voltage that is supplied could range from 21V to 26V (or more) from a 24V lead acid battery. If the load needs a regulated voltage, you'll need to add a voltage regulator or the load might not function correctly.

If your going the other way around, since the load expects an range of voltages of probably 5 lithium cells which would be 16-21V if you have a regulated supply with 18V that should work assuming you have more current than the battery could supply.

Make sure you don't make the cable too high resistance or the voltage drop on the cable could be high enough to cause problems.